# Running docker image as root user and service as non root user

Tags: docker, docker-compose

From a security perspective, I am trying to understand the difference between

- Running the image itself as a non-root user with `USER` directive in dockerfile
- Running the image as root and running the service alone as non-root
  user

In second option, there will be a startup script which runs as root and starts the service as non-root user.

Are these two equivalent? Is the second option vulnerable considering the startup script is running as root? Does it matter if it exits (or if it doesn't) after starting the service ?

Excuse me if this question is already asked and answered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The really important thing is that, once your service is up and running, it’s not running as root.  (This is a little less important in Docker than not, but “don’t be root” is still considered a best practice.)  Both options you propose are valid approaches.

Your second option, “start up as root and then drop privileges”, isn’t common in Docker, but it matches in spirit what most Unix daemons do.  The [official Hashicorp Consul image](https://github.com/hashicorp/docker-consul/tree/b29407b8716fba0c5781f6c6800bf46ef3700cf7/0.X) is the one thing I know of that actually does it.  In particular, it expects to start up with some data directory mounted, so it `chown -R consul` the data directory as root before the daemon proper starts.  I’d expect this to be a pretty typical use of this pattern.

If you don’t need to do this sort of pre-launch setup, specifying some arbitrary non-root `USER` at the end of your `Dockerfile` is mechanically easier and checks the same “don’t be root” box.

There are many SO questions around trying to run a container as the current host user, or trying to run a tool packaged in Docker against the host filesystem.  This is awkward, since a key design goal of Docker is to isolate the containers from these host details.  If you need to choose the user the container process is running as, you want the standard `docker run -u` option and would need the first option.

Comment: Thanks David! This is good information. Completely agree with you on docker is little more dependent on host filesystem than I expected!